# Large difference in number of cases in each category of a variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, sample, binary-data

I want to run an analysis on a data set. However, the primary predictor variable (5 point scale) varies greatly in size of each group. I plan to create a dichotomous variable from these 5 category. The 0 value would include 75.4% of cases (n=1728), while the 1 value would only include 24.6% of cases (n=567).

What is the general rule of thumb for lowest percentage of a category, in a dichotomous variable, necessary to run a regression analysis?

and Can i run a regression analysis using this data?

Thank you

Comment: I gave an answer, but also have a question. You say the predictor variable has 5 levels, but it is either 0 or 1 100% of the time (75.4 + 24.6 = 100). What about those other 3 levels?

Comment: There can be no such (valid) rule of thumb because *percentage* is immaterial: what matters are the *counts* in each category. Since you have only six categories, why don't you let us know the six counts in your dataset?  Even better would be information about the distributions of the dependent variable values broken down by the six categories (which you could provide graphically, say with side-by-side boxplots). What is the nature of the other covariates (since "primary" suggests there are others available)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the predictor variable, not the response - right? In that case, I don't know of a rule of thumb. This doesn't by itself invalidate any distributional assumptions, but small frequencies at some levels of that predictor make the standard errors large when predicting at those levels.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into zero-inflated regression models (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-inflated_model). They're a good fit for your type of data.

Comment: Zero-inflated models deal with *dependent* variables that exhibit many zeros. How would you propose applying them to this question which concerns an *independent* variable?

Comment: If that is the case, then I misunderstood the question and my answer is incorrect